Angular 18 post request - node:_http_outgoing:659 throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
I'm sending a basic post request to my backend. All others request are working fine, but in this specific & new case, I'm getting a strange error:
node:_http_outgoing:659
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:659:11)
    at setOriginHeader...

I'm using Angular 18 , node 20.15.0 and I'm behind a proxy. My code in service:
sendData(id, data):Observable<any>{
return this.http.post(`${environment.url}/${id}`, data);
}

Can be this a backend issue? Read that if multiple responses are sent, then this error can be raised.

Are you using SSR? Are you using HttpClient with fetch?

Didn't used it withFetch(). Gave it a try now, same error. Now that I'm looking, seems to be an issue for all POST requests after the update to Angular v18.

Are you using SSR? Do you have any interceptors, and if yes can you try if temporarily removing them resolves the issue?

I'm not using SSSR. I have an interceptor which basically add on the header the Auth token. The "GET" requests are working fine. I had initially some issue from proxy config file after Angular update to v18, but managed to fix them. Now, seems POST requests are not working correctly.

Does disabling/removing the interceptor temporarily fix the issue? If yes, then please add the code of the interceptor to the question.

No, it's not. The interceptor is needed. I extract the token with AWS Amplify and have to add it on the request.

Seems to be an issue from proxy.conf.json file. GET requests are working fine but others: DELETE/PUT/POST are basically breaking the app.

this is usually server side error. you should include backend (aws??, node http??, express??) routes on which it throws the error, also, check if you have some middleware on those routes that maybe ends the response, before the route handler does (the usual sceneario for this error)

I honestly think is from proxy conf file in Angular 18. Former config file was not working at all after the update. Fixed it and seemed to be working, but still for requests excepting GET requests is not working.

how did you fix it? I'd inspect those requests, most likely the requests are missing some header or data, and on the server it probably triggers two handlers, of which both try to end response...

I had this error on my cypress test.
I found a work arround, in the package.json i added:
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "7.2.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "7.2.1"
  }

No more issues

Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't resolve my issue.

For me it did solve the issue.
